# In MongoDb, with a Projection, remove array with one empty object [{}]

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

In MongoDb, with a Projection, I want to remove an array that contains one empty object **[{}]** resulting from a $unwind preserveNullAndEmptyArrays & group.

```
[{
  "title": "Papaye",
  "childrens": [{}],
  "parents": [{
      "title": "Arbres fruitiers",
      "url": "/documents/plantes/arboriculture/arbres-fruitiers"
    }
  ],
  "url": "/documents/plantes/arboriculture/arbres-fruitiers/papaye"
},
{
  "title": "Arbres fruitiers",
  "childrens": [{
      "title": "Tavelure",
      "url": "/documents/maladies/tavelure"
    },
    {
      "title": "Longane",
      "url": "/documents/plantes/arboriculture/arbres-fruitiers/longane"
    }],
  "parents": [{
      "title": "Arboriculture",
      "url": "/documents/plantes/arboriculture"
     }],
 "url": "/documents/plantes/arboriculture/arbres-fruitiers"
}
```

Pipeline like :

```
var pipeline = [];
pipeline.push({$match:{url:/^\//}});
(...)
var proj = {};
proj.title = true;
proj.parents = true;
proj.url = true;

proj.parents = ???
proj.childrens = ???

pipeline.push({$project:proj});
db.getCollection('Pages').aggregate(pipeline)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution. Just test if url is null for the first array entry.

```
proj.childrens = {
    "$cond", [
                "$eq", [
                        "$arrayElemAt",["$childrens.url",0],
                        null
                    ],
                [],
                "$childrens"
              ]
};
```